# Twilio java Helper library issues

Tags: java, twilio

I am having issues with using Twilio and java. I am trying to make a Minecraft plugin that sends an alert to admins. I have added the required dependency to my POM.xml file, but it has the error "Dependency not found", and in the main java class file I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol"

Information:
Maven
InteliJ
And I am using a Minecraft development plugin

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.
Have you tried

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Intellij
- Invalidating caches/Restart
- Deleting the maven folder in the .Intellij folder and deleting the *.iml and .idea folder and restarted Intellij
- Right-clicking on project, clicking on maven, and clicking reimport
- running `mvn clean install -U`

Let me know if these help at all or if your tried them already!